# When writing a jquery function? How can I go about adding:nth-child to $(this) inside the function?

Tags: navigation, html-lists, siblings, jquery

I need to build navigation with jQuery by grabbing the current year making it the first nav element. Then building other list items to display the subsequent years... my problem is targeting the siblings of the list items inside of a jQuery function which i want to be able to do so I can easily run that function on multiple pages... here is what I have so far... i can set up a fiddle if it will help just request it.

This is the successful/working code but not wrapped in a jQuery function:

```
$currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
$navListEl = $("#yearNav li").length; // = 7
$lastYear=0;
for (var i=1;i<$navListEl+1;i++)
{  
    $("#yearNav li"+":nth-child("+i+")").append($currentYear-$lastYear);
    $lastYear++;
}
```

First Try:

```
jQuery.fn.createNav = function(){
    $currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
    $navListEl = $(this).length; // = 7
    alert('hey');
    $lastYear=0;
    for (var i=1;i<$navListEl+1;i++)
    {  
        $(this+":nth-child("+i+")").append($currentYear-$lastYear);
        $lastYear++;
    }
}

$("#yearNav li").createNav();
```

Second Try: (This one works kinda but duplicates the nmbers on each li item instead of once on each)

```
jQuery.fn.createNav = function(){
    $currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
    $navListEl = $(this).length; // = 7
    $lastYear = 0;
    for (var i=1;i<$navListEl+1;i++)
    {  
        $(this).append($currentYear-$lastYear);
        $lastYear++;
    }
}

$("#yearNav li").siblings().createNav();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to Musa's answer, if you want to avoid re-running the selector for every element then you can iterate over the list of selected elements just once with either of these two approaches:

1. Use the `eq()` method in a for loop to access each element in the list by index:

   ```
   jQuery.fn.createNav = function(){
       $currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
       $navListEl = $(this).length; // = 7
       $lastYear = 0;

       for (var i = 0; i < $navListEl; i++)
       {
           $(this).eq(i).append($currentYear - $lastYear);
           $lastYear++;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use the `each()` method to iterate over each element in turn:

   ```
   jQuery.fn.createNav = function(){
       $currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
       $navListEl = $(this).length; // = 7
       $lastYear = 0;

       $(this).each(function(){
           $(this).append($currentYear - $lastYear);
           $lastYear++;
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: Great Sly!! I was actually using the second answer but I wanted to know how to append the nth-child to $(this) but You for sure get a check and a thumbs up for this answer as it will probably help someone else looking for some type of answer... its definetly the most simple and is the best method for this particular example I provided... Thanks Sly for your answer!!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(this.selector+":nth-child("+i+")").append($currentYear-$lastYear);
```

Comment: Nice completely forgot about that, Worked like a charm! Musa You are the man sir!